# Scroll over to get definition

Tags: content, the-content, plugin-contact-form-7

I need to have content appear when I scroll over certain words or groups of words. Eg. If I scroll over the word pastor. I should see a definition of Pastor appear next to the word.I would like to write in the definition myself.

Comment: What have you tried already, and how is that related to the plugin Contact form 7?

Comment: Like toscho said how is this related to contact form 7? Could you please provide us with more information and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've used a plugin called [Tippy for ToolTips](http://croberts.me/tippy-for-wordpress/) that brings up a box with your words when you mouseover. That said, if you search the plugins directory on the WordPress Codex for "tooltips" you'll find oodles of choices. Having just done so, I think [WordPress Tooltips](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-tooltips/) might be a good option for your needs. Good luck with the site.